# Execute Jar file in IDE and get the output (String)?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

Is it possible to execute a Jar file on my IDE (IntelliJ) to get the output string for my own purpose on the project that I have?

I know that we can make system calls, but in this case I want to add a Jar file on my project and execute it whenever I want it.

For example: I have a project on IntelliJ, one of my classes (on this project) needs to get the output by running the Jar file (which is on my project).

On my terminal, I would do something like `java -jar <jar_file>.jar <file>.asm` and this would output a result to my terminal.
And I want to get that output from this command on my Java Class.

Comment: "I know that we can call system calls" - and have you tried running a jar file? If not, why not?

Comment: `to get the output string for my own purpose on the project that I have`. Please can you make this clearer and dictate _exactly_ what you want to do.

Comment: I added more information on my topic, thank you for the answers. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Jar file returns an output string, so I assume, it's main-method could look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("output string");
}
```

And now, if you want to use this "output string" string in your own class, you could do it like this:

```
public class YourClass {
...

    public String getOutputStringFromJar() {
        String s = ""; // or = null;

        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar full/path/to/your/Jar.jar full/path/to/fibonacci.asm");// just like you would do it on your terminal
            p.waitFor();

            InputStream is = p.getInputStream();

            byte b[] = new byte[is.available()];
            is.read(b, 0, b.length); // probably try b.length-1 or -2 to remove "new-line(s)"

            s = new String(b);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return s;
    }
...
}
```

Now you have the method, that returns the output string, and you can use it however you want, and you know how to execute a Jar file from your project whenever you want

Comment: let me try this tonight ! :)

Comment: Thank you !!! It works perfectly and that's what I wanted ! :))
Thank you so much !!!

Answer (score 0):

Your ask is not precise, but if i understand what you're doing, you run the Mars.jar with .asm file in param, and you got an output like in the [this link with Fibonacci numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsKLK.png)

and now you want to get the Fibonacci numbers in your program? if that is what you need, i would suggest you to decompile the jar to understand his content

When you do so, you'll see that the main class in the jar is like this

```
 public class Mars {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     new mars.MarsLaunch(args);
  }
}
```

so simply when you add the jar to your class path, you need to do somthing like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    // this will redirect your system output to a file named output.txt
    PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"));
    System.setOut(out);


    String [] myAsmFile = {"C:/produits/Fibonacci.asm"};

    new mars.MarsLaunch(myAsmFile);
    // and then you can read the output.txt file

}
```

hope this help you

Comment: Yes this is what I want ! But, I do not know if this will work !
I saw that MarsLaunch Class has this comment !
`// running from command line.
            // assure command mode works in headless environment (generates exception if not)` I will try it out and see !

Comment: I tried and got exception (I was really expecting this sincerely)...
The Class MarsLaunch has some code which will output an exception if the class isn't being executed on a terminal...

Comment: what is the exception? share the stack, it works for me and write the output to my output.txt file

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at mars.MarsLaunch.<init>(MarsLaunch.java:131)
 at mars.Main.main(Main.java:17)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: its just a nullPointerException, there is no restriction on the jar, and it works fine for me with the example i post, you should see the parameter you launch with

Comment: Well i have an empty file :( with the Fibonacci.asm file ! And the result shouldn't be empty ! Can you show me your project ?